# How to add element in copy of array without adding to the copied array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to make a jagged array that copies the last list of the array, and then modifies only the last list, without modifying any list before it.

This is my code:

```
list=[[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d']]
list.append(list[-1])
list[-1].append('apple')
print(list)
```

I get: [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'apple'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'apple']]

But I want to get: [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'apple']]

How do I add to the last list, without adding to the previous ones?